# How to do "hit any key" in python?

Tags: python

How would I do a "hit any key" (or grab a menu option) in Python?

- raw_input requires you hit return.
- Windows msvcrt has getch() and getche().

Is there a portable way to do this using the standard libs?

Comment: Where's the "any" key? I don't have one on my keyboard

Comment: +1 for obvious use of a cliche.

Comment: @Patrick Why don't you have the "one" key on your keyboard? Rest of the numbers are fine? Did you lose "1"? Or you find entering "1" via ASCII key combinations enjoyable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
try:
    # Win32
    from msvcrt import getch
except ImportError:
    # UNIX
    def getch():
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            return sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
```

Comment: Try to run this from an IDE under linux and you will get `termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')`. isatty() is not safe!

Comment: Doesn't `termios` imply that it's run from a terminal (a `tty` if you will)?

Comment: this doesn't get shift / control / etc. Do you know of a way to do that as well?

Comment: For ones who want a simple replace of `raw_input()` with ability to exit on `Ctrl-C`: 
`if ord(getch())==3: sys.exit()`

Comment: For me, `fd = sys.stdin.fileno()` fails with message `AttributeError: fileno`.

Comment: Non-portable solution. OP asked for "standard libs." msvcrt is def not standard on my linux box.

Answer (score 10):

```
try:
  os.system('pause')  #windows, doesn't require enter
except whatever_it_is:
  os.system('read -p "Press any key to continue"') #linux
```

Comment: +1 for it is a simple solution, probably good enough for 90% of all cases.

Comment: I just tested with Python 2.x and 3.x on Windows Vista, and it does not require Enter here.  (Still does not handle something like indicating a menu choice via a single key press - but works at least on Vista for the "press any key to continue" case.)

Comment: spawning a sub-process for io sync is just plain useless.  do not do this, it will ruin non-interactive performance for no good reason.

Comment: Regardless of performance considerations, calling out to an external application for such a simple task is idiotic.

Comment: what the heck?  Wasting even 10 minutes writing 15 lines of code when a mindless one liner will do is worse.

Comment: Works fine in Python 2.7 on Windows 7:
>>> def pause(): import os; os.system('pause')
...
>>> pause()
Press any key to continue . . .
>>>

Comment: Also, TokenMacGuy, waiting for any key to be pressed IS interactive performance. And JohnMillikin, specialized tools ARE the Unix philosophy.

Comment: Same code, but instead of try-except I'd use platform.system() guards. You never know whether somebody reserved /opt/bin/pause because it's free anyways ...

Comment: Python3.4 on Ubuntu: The call to 'os.system' is weird. It doesn't raise at all, but instead prints some text to stderr and returns an int, presumably the child process id. I don't know how to detect that the system call didn't work, other than something yucky like wrapping stderr.

Answer (score 7):

A couple years ago I wrote a small library to do this in a cross-platform way (inspired directly by John Millikin's answer above). In addition to `getch`, it comes with a `pause` function that prints `'Press any key to continue . . .'`:

```
pause()
```

You can provide a custom message too:

```
pause('Hit any key')
```

If the next step is to exit, it also comes with a convenience function that calls `sys.exit(status)`:

```
pause_exit(status=0, message='Hit any key')
```

Install with `pip install py-getch`, or [check it out here](https://github.com/joeyespo/py-getch).

Comment: easy to use and works great. thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 6):

From the [python docs](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/library/#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time):

```
import termios, fcntl, sys, os
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)

oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

try:
    while 1:
        try:
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            print "Got character", `c`
        except IOError: pass
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

This only works for Unix variants though. I don't think there is a cross-platform way.

Comment: This should be the solution.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it consumes all available CPU cycles running the while loop. You can reduce this to almost nothing by inserting `time.sleep(0.1)` in the loop. If you insert this in place of "pass", then the loop will process strings of keystrokes as fast as possible, but when idle it will only check for characters 10 times a second.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it like the following in Windows. 
   `getch()` takes a one single character

```
import msvcrt
char = 0
print 'Press any key to continue'
while not char:
    char = msvcrt.getch()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
import keyboard
print("Press any key to continue")
keyboard.read_key()
print("to be continued...")
```

Comment: I get this error with this method `ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux. `

Answer (score 0):

on linux platform, I use `os.system` to call `/sbin/getkey` command, e.g.

```
continue_ = os.system('/sbin/getkey -m "Please any key within %d seconds to continue..." -c  10')
if continue_:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

The benefit is it will show an countdown seconds to user, very interesting :)