# is there a way to use input("Press any key to continue") on version 2.6

Tags: python, input

I want the program to pause and wait until you press any key to continue, but raw_input() is going away, and input() is replacing it.  So I have
var = input("Press enter to continue") and it waits until I press enter, but then it fails with `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while Parsing`.
This works OK on a system with Python 3, but this is linux Python 2.6 and I hate to have to code in raw_input() since it is going away.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the **actual** code and **actual** error messages that you're **actually** getting.

Comment: This shouldn't be a syntax error - Python 2.6 supports the `input` function. Could you show us the rest of your code please?

Comment: @smashery: it will still cause a syntax error if the entered expression contains an syntax error, for example just pressing enter

Comment: Ah, seems I misread the question. Cheers.

Comment: Probably useful for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394956/how-to-do-hit-any-key-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this

```
try:
    input= raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```

If `raw_input` exists, it will be used for input.  If it doesn't exist, `input` still exists.

Comment: I like this one.  Worked great. and is simple

Comment: +1 Although I think it would have been better if there was a `__future__` import for this, there isn't, so this is the best way

Answer (score 3):

you could do something on the line of ...

```
def myinput(prompt):
    try:
        return raw_input(prompt)
    except NameError:
        return input(prompt)
```

... but **don't**.

Instead, just use `raw_input()` on your program, and then use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) to convert the file to python 3.x. That will convert all the `raw_input()`s for you and also other stuff you might be missing.

That's the recommended way to keep a software working on both python 2 and python 3 and also keep sanity.

Comment: but if I just move the file between two boxes, I hate to have to convert all the time

Comment: No, it does an eval of the input. You'll need to change how input is defined. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.sys('pause')
```

You can use this module on Windows.