# What is the equivalence of cin.ignore() in python?

Tags: python, c++, cin, keystroke

In C++, i could use `cin.ignore()` to get a keystroke from user before program continues.

**What is the equivalence of `cin.ignore()` in python?**

Comment: @P0W: `raw_input()` does not return until <Enter> is pressed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394956/how-to-do-hit-any-key-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
raw_input("Press enter to exit...") # use input() if using Python 3.x
```

This only works with pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, however (the user could type in a bunch of letters but only pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end).