# Python: Allow keypress signals from gtk.window to stop a loop

Tags: python, keyboard, gtk

So, essentially, I want something that can do this:

```
def onKeyPress(widget, event):
    if event.state & gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK and keyname == "a":
        Stop the loop somehow.

def doLoop(widget):
    while True:
        print "You're in"
        print "a loop"


mywindow = gtk.Window()
mywindow.connect("key_press_event", onKeyPress)
foo = gtk.Foo()
foo.connect("bar", doLoop)
mywindow.add(foo)
```

I don't know how to accomplish this, but I have tried using threading or different .py files, but I am kind of a beginner, so I want to know if there's an easier way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394956/how-to-do-hit-any-key-in-python

Answer (score -1):

Try having a boolean called KeyPressed that can be accessed from both the doLoop and onKeyPress functions. Then you can do this:

```
def onKeyPress(widget, event):
    if event.state & gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK and keyname == "a":
        KeyPressed = False

def doLoop(widget):
    while KeyPressed:
        print "You're in"
        print "a loop"


mywindow = gtk.Window()
mywindow.connect("key_press_event", onKeyPress)
foo = gtk.Foo()
foo.connect("bar", doLoop)
mywindow.add(foo)
```

KeyPressed would have to be set to True from the beginning.

Comment: Can you tell why? I don't have gtk so I can't debug. Is KeyPressed being set to False?

Comment: Well, the loop is too busy, well, doing itself to allow the code to respond to mywindow.